# Missing rows of GridView in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `GridView` in a `CoordinationLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>
      <GridView .../>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The GridView displays normally outside of the `CoordinatorLayout` but inside, it only display the first row. How to fix it? Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you targeting less than API 21?

Comment: The build gradle says: targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Look at your **build.gradle** file & then look at the **compileSdkVersion**. If it is **21** or above, try `gridview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);`

Comment: Thanks, it is now scrollable. But i still have to set a fixed height to display all the content.

Comment: GridView shouldn't be the first item in coordinator layout